# Is Elasticsearch Scroll API not recommended for real-time pagination?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

I understand that Elasticsearch Scroll API is not intended for real-time user requests. But would it be bad if it's used for that? I have a requirement to implement paginated results (to be displayed on web frontend) and `from`/`size` approach is returning duplicates across pages. Presumably because I have a sharded setup (with no replicas at all). I've tried setting `preference`but it did not help.

Scroll API does not seem to have this issue, I'm wondering if it's really bad to use it for my use case?

Thanks

Comment: for real time is recommended search after query. Read in the documentation why https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-search-after.html#search-request-search-after

Comment: Which version of elastic search are you using?

Comment: @Lupanoide that seems amazing, I'll look into that! thank you

Comment: @GauravArya - I'm using 5.4, but open to upgrade to 6 if that's relevant to the issue

Comment: If it is 5.4 then you should definitely use search_after i was asking as before elasticsearch 5 this feature was not available.This is the best to use

Comment: Many thanks folks, I used `search_after` and it worked extremely well!!

Comment: @GauravArya @Lupanoide, I'm a bit curious though, any idea why traditional `from`, `size` approach produces duplicates across pages in sharded setup even when there are no replicas? I went through the example mentioned in [Deep Paging in Distributed Systems](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html) and could not see how it would return some documents again in subsequent pages.

Answer (score 1):

Results from a scrolling search reflect the state of the index at the time of the initial search request. Subsequent indexing or document changes only affect later search and scroll requests. it means that your pagination is based on the time you requested the search result, so you don't see new document or will see deleted in your result. Also Scroll API is not recommended by ES for deep pagination any more(ES 7.x). you can find more info on ElasticSearch documentation page: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/scroll-api.html

Answer (score 0):

On the question 'why you get duplicate results', I think this is caused by intermediate indexing.  When doing independent search calls with pagination, each call runs independently (still using some caching). So if you ask the first 100, you get the first 100 at that time. When then asking x seconds later the 'next' 100, you get 100 - 199 at x seconds later. If meanwhile a new document got indexed which logically fits in the first 100, it will push the rest further. This way, your result 100 (first in the second results) might have been #99 in the first call. When then gluing them together in the UI, you see the same result twice.
Both scroll and search-after are designed to refer ES back to the original call, indicating it that you want to continue counting from that moment onwards.

I have not found a good explanation though *why* search_after is better than scroll.

I *assume* that scroll is optimized for the use case where you will go through the entire set anyway (so the pagination is to avoid overloading the client and the pipe between ES and client with too big chunks at once). While search_after is optimized for the use case where you are likely to only go a few pages far/deep (it is known that human users tend to stay on the first page with a quickly lowering frequency of going much further, because you would force your eyes to find something into overwhelming amounts of information). Implementing good filters in the user interface is the much better approach.